# Prove the inequality $|1-t^{1/n}|\le \frac{e}{n}$ for $t \in [1,e].$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I prove that for all $t \in [1,e]$ we have
$$|1-t^{1/n}|\le \frac{e}{n}$$

I have tried to use the mean value theorem on the sub interval $[1,t]$

so $|1-t^{1/n}|=|1-t|| \frac{c^{1-\frac{1}{n}}}{n}|$ for $c$ in the interval $[1,e]$

where can I go from this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\int_1^{t} s^{\frac 1 n -1}ds=n(t^{1/n}-1)$. Note that $\int_1^{t} s^{\frac 1 n -1}ds\leq \int_1^{e}e^{1/n-1}ds=e^{1/n} \leq e$.

Answer (score 0):

If $\delta = n(t^{1/n} - 1)$, then $\delta > 0$ and $(1 + \frac{\delta}{n})^n = t$. By the binomial theorem $t > n(\frac{\delta}{n}) = \delta$, so $e > \delta$ and hence $0 < t^{1/n} - 1 < \frac{e}{n}$.